# Googlecharts with rails without plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-visualization

I am trying to implement charts in my Rails project. Are there any good tutorials to implement "**GoogleCharts**" in Rails 3.0.6 **without** using any plugin?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works :

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline.html

Adding the source code in html page and passing parameter declared in the rails controller to the html page.